# Can I use the Samsung Galaxy S5's Finger Scanner as a finger-print scanner for laptop?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

Can I use my Samsung Galaxy S5's finger scanner as a finger-print scanner for my laptop? Because I want to register on a site that requires my fingerprint from home. My phone is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the general practice ongoing is that androids by default only support being connected as camera or as mtp to PC. So by default atleast this is not possible.
However, you can make it support by adding some module in kernel for this purpose. But since no such such module exists (ayleast not the one I could find), so you will have to create one yourself and implement it.